# ffmpeg upgrade or reinstalling on CentOS

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to upgrade ffmpeg installed on my linux server following this link: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Centos

It's not working. Sometimes it gives error "Host is not communicating" in WinSCP when I try this command:

```
# yum install autoconf automake cmake freetype-devel gcc gcc-c++ git libtool make mercurial nasm pkgconfig zlib-devel
```

But once I tried this and it gets installed. But after installing all the things mentioned in that link, the problem was still there. I deleted all the files installed using that link and tried again but the above command starts giving me that error again. Is it a path issue or something else? I can't find where my old ffmpeg is installed.

Is it necessary to uninstall the old version and install the new one or will upgrading using above mentioned link work?

Comment: Is it this message? [Host is not communicating for more than 15 seconds. Still waiting... Warning: Aborting this operation will close connection!](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/message_host_is_not_communicating)

Answer (score 1):

A nice fellow named John van Sickle maintains up-to-date static builds of ffmpeg at http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/.

Static build ofcourse means, the binary is largish, but you simply don't care for a two-page dependency list.

I always wanted to thank John - looks like a good place to do so here.